# What do we do with an answer with a meme in it?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I found this. [How to count empty accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10369)

### What do we deal with these kind of answers?

To the future I saved in [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202154920/https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/how-to-count-empty-accounts)

[image: useless yes :D]

Comment: Mind explaining what bothers you?

Comment: @5chdn I am just curious whether it violates any terms or not. IMO there is nothing in relation to the question. It will not help any future visitors at all as such.

Comment: Actually, the meme _is_ answering the question.

Answer (score 4):

I have to admit it's the first time I see *such* an answer and therefore I think we really don't need to fear getting flooded with memes.

As already discussed in the comments, for this question the generated meme is actually *answering* the the question with a slight hint of humor. I personally like it.

I would say it's legit as long

- the meme is on-topic.
- as the answer is not meme-only.

The author subsequently explains what he means when he states, *there are no accounts*.